# How to merge specific column values in a pandas using an aggregate

Tags: pandas

I have a large IP address file and convert it to decimal value and how to merge the values of two columns without changing the first value

I created an aggregation group in my pandas code, but it does not calculate my merge value

my output:

```
  ip_cut  Code    Range   Ip
  16777   AU      256    16777216
  16777   CN      256    16777472
  16777   CN      512    16777728
  16778   AU     1024    16778240
  16843   CN     1536    16843264
  16844   CN      256    16844800
  16845   CN     1792    16845056
  16846   CN     4096    16846848
```

how to add range merging totals
`16777472+256 =16777728`
The second value is unnecessary just by adding the same country code as the range and obtaining the first value.

How to get expected output like this(The second value is unnecessary)

```
Code    Range   Ip 
AU       256    16777216
CN       768    16777472
AU       1024   16778240
CN       7680   16843264
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd

file = "/Users/roc/Desktop/js/ttest/delegated2.txt"

df = pd.read_csv(file,sep=' ',header=None,error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False,names=['Ip','Range','Code'],low_memory=False)


df['ip_cut'] = df['Ip'].astype(str)
df['ip_cut'] = df['ip_cut'].str[:5]

df1 = df.groupby(['ip_cut','Code'],as_index=False).agg({'Range':lambda x: x.sum(), 'Ip':'first'})
new = df1.sort_values('Ip', ascending=True)

print(new)
```

Comment: Can you add few more lines in your input and show us expected output for it.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Additional information output and code added

Comment: Its a duplicate, use aggregate. df.groupby('code', as_index = False).agg({'ip':'first', 'range':'sum'})

Comment: adding df['Range']=df.groupby('Code', as_index = False).agg({'Ip':'first', 'Range':'sum'}) ?

Comment: Try executing df.groupby('Code', as_index = False).agg({'Ip':'first', 'Range':'sum'}) . It returns a Dataframe, not a series. So you can not assign it to existing dataframe as a column

Comment: You can save the dataframe to a new object, new_df = df.groupby('Code', as_index = False).agg({'Ip':'first', 'Range':'sum'})

Comment: If I use this I lose most of my IP data and my output is agg after 240 lines [200217 lines] and most IP addresses are gone